# Filter.js inside ReactJS

Tags: javascript, filter, reactjs

I would insert a component with Filter.js(https://github.com/jiren/filter.js) inside the ReactJs, someone already doing this? 
When I inserted the script "template" in ReactJS gives unexpected token in "<%=".

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
    <div>
        <input type="text" className="form-control searchBox" id="search_box" placeholder="Employees" />
      <div className="featured_list_find list-group" id="service_list"></div>
      <script id="template" type="text/html">
        <a className="list-group-item" data-id="<%= m %>">
      </script>
    </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nankym/m7v1p8dw/

Tnks

Comment: `<%= m %>` is PHP I'm guessing... not valid JSX

Comment: @DominicTobias this is the lib js that manager - https://github.com/jiren/filter.js

Comment: I'm quite sure this won't work in React. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @Chris Basically I'm trying to make a filter like this: http://jiren.github.io/filter.js/pagination.html on a component of reactJs.

Comment: I already used the escape, but, won't work {'<%= m %>'}, show me the string.

Comment: With escape, comes this way: data-matricula="&lt;%= m %&gt;" but the Filter.js don't plays.

Answer (score 0):

I fork the lib and I changed the code to resolve the problem.

Change the HTML entity before read the template, does it work.

https://github.com/jiren/filter.js/pull/125